# how do I get the help message and positional arguments description on the same line?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

here is my code, it is in the main method.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--hello",type=str, metavar= "{greetings}", help ="prints hello")
```

this is what my help message looks like when in run `main.py -h`

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --hello {greetings}
                        prints hello
```

but I want it to do this:

```
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --hello {greetings}        prints hello
```

I want the `--hello {greetings}`  and `prints hello` to be on the same line.
How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use a wider terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `argparse.HelpFormatter` and set the `width` and `max_help_positions` default values according to the whatever size you think appropriate.  Then pass your subclass when initializing your parser as the `formatter_class` parameter.

like this:

```
import argparse

class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self, prog, width=50, max_help_positions=50): # adjust default values
        super().__init__(prog, width=width, max_help_positions=max_help_positions)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=MyHelpFormatter)
```